# XSLT: is it possible to mark-up portions of text within a text node, based on the position of inline elements within the surrounding element?

Tags: xml, xslt, text

Or should something else be done to achieve this?

For example, can this:

```
<p> <name>William Cuthbert Faulkner</name> (born Falkner, September 25, 1897 – 
July 6, 1962) was an American writer from Oxford, Mississippi. <name>James 
Augustine Aloysius Joyce</name> (2 February 1882 – 13 January 1941) was an Irish
novelist and poet. <name>Adeline Virginia Woolf</name> (pronounced /wʊlf/; 25
January 1882 – 28 March 1941) was an English author, essayist, publisher, and
writer of short stories.</p>
```

be transformed into this?

```
<authors> 
  <author>
     <name>William Cuthbert Faulkner</name>
     <description> (born Falkner, September 25, 1897 – July 6, 1962) was an American
     writer from Oxford, Mississippi. </description> 
  </author>
  <author>
     <name>James Augustine Aloysius Joyce</name> 
     <description>(2 February 1882 – 13 January 1941) was an Irish novelist and
     poet.</description>
  </author>
  <author>
    <name>Adeline Virginia Woolf</name>
    <description>(pronounced /wʊlf/; 25 January 1882 – 28 March 1941) was an English
     author, essayist, publisher, and writer of short stories.</description>
  </author>
</authors>
```

Comment: To put it simply. Yes you can use xslt to do this. The real question however is whether your input will remain the same?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it...

This XSLT 1.0 Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <authors>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </authors>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <author>
      <name><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/></name>
      <description>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(following-sibling::text()[1])"/>
      </description>
    </author>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[preceding-sibling::name[1]]"/>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces the following output when applied to the input from your question:

```
<authors>
   <author>
      <name>William Cuthbert Faulkner</name>
      <description>(born Falkner, September 25, 1897 – July 6, 1962) was an American writer from Oxford, Mississippi.</description>
   </author>
   <author>
      <name>James Augustine Aloysius Joyce</name>
      <description>(2 February 1882 – 13 January 1941) was an Irish novelist and poet.</description>
   </author>
   <author>
      <name>Adeline Virginia Woolf</name>
      <description>(pronounced /wʊlf/; 25 January 1882 – 28 March 1941) was an English author, essayist, publisher, and writer of short stories.</description>
   </author>
</authors>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <authors>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="p/name"/>
        </authors>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <author>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </name>
            <description>
                <xsl:value-of select="../text()[count(current()/preceding-sibling::*) + 1]"/>
            </description>
        </author>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What processor are you using? When I run it with Saxon I get an empty description for the first name and the following 2 names have incorrect discriptions.

Comment: That's interesting, I ran in in XMLSpy and it looks ok there. Strange.

Comment: Also, there are no `author` elements wrapping name and description.

Comment: What processor does XMLSpy use?

Comment: It uses Altova's processor. By the way, I even specifically tested it as an XSLT 1 and XSLT 2 stylesheet (same result). Any difference with Saxon in that respect?

Comment: I tried it as an XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 with Saxon 6.5.5 and Saxon 9.3 (HE/PE/EE) and got the same results. The strange thing is that I tried it with MSXML 6 and it came out ok. (Still missing the `author` elements, but that isn't a big deal.) Can you please edit your question so I can remove my downvote? Thanks :-)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Can you please edit your question"? Can't you just upvote it again? You're right about the missing `<author>` element; that was an oversight I have fixed now. Thanks :-)

Comment: Never mind...I had to upvote then downvote and then remove the downvote.

Comment: I think the code as written is very sensitive to the first whitespace text node preceding the name element, which the MSXML parser (and therefore AltovaXML) incorrectly ignores.

Comment: Ah, that looks plausible. So (without having tried it with Saxon) I suppose in the output, the descriptions are shifted, and the fix would be to write `+ 2` instead of `+ 1`. Thanks for clearing up that mystery!

Comment: Changing it to `+ 2` will work for Saxon and Xalan, but not for MSXML. Also, if the first whitespace after `<p>` is removed it won't work correctly in either one. As Dr. Kay pointed out, I think this code is too sensitive for anything other than MSXML.